# Do you refit the model after getting the best parameter from RandomizedSearchCV/GridSearchCV,?

Tags: python, cross-validation, random-forest

I am reading a tutorial about RandomizedSerchCV [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-the-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-28d2aa77dd74) and I am still confused about what to do after getting the best parameter values. I hope that you could confirm my understanding.

Here's the code referred from the blog post above

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

# Number of trees in random forest
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]

# Number of features to consider at every split
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']

# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)

# Minimum number of samples required to split a node
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]

# Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]

# Method of selecting samples for training each tree
bootstrap = [True, False]

# Create the random grid
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}
pprint(random_grid)

# Instantiate model with 1000 decision trees
rfr = RandomForestRegressor()

# Random search of parameters, using 3 fold cross validation, 
# search across 100 different combinations, and use all available cores
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rfr, 
                               param_distributions = random_grid, 
                               n_iter = 100, 
                               cv = 3, 
                               verbose=2, 
                               random_state=0, 
                               n_jobs = -1)
# Fit the random search model
rf_random.fit(X_train, y_train())
```

After fitting the model, I've printed the best paramter

```
rf_random.best_params_
```

and this is the result

***{'n_estimators': 400,
'min_samples_split': 2,
'min_samples_leaf': 1,
'max_features': 'sqrt',
'max_depth': None,
'bootstrap': False}***

My question is that, after getting the best parameters above, what do I have to do next between

***Option 1 : Use those parameters and refit the model again just like this.***

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 400,
                            min_samples_split = 2,
                            min_samples_leaf = 1,
                            max_features = 'sqrt',
                            max_depth = None,
                            bootstrap = False
                           )

rfr.fit(X_train, y_train) 

pred_rfr = rfr.predict(X_test)
```

OR

***Option 2 : I can just use .predict without having to do the whole process again***

```
pred_rfr = rf_random.predict(X_test)
```

If both options are wrong, could you please guide me what to do next?
Thank you so much for your kind answer.

Comment: We had exactly the same question asked few days ago, so I marked it as a duplicate of yours.

Comment: @Tim Thank you so much for pointing out the post that answer my question!